# Mvc 5 While Editing the Date value, Box do not let me choose new date if i fill it with

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have date field that both i want it to be filled with current value and let me choose the date at the same time but this is not happening. 
When i do model.CourseDate.Date to EditorFor line like this:

```
   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CourseDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CourseDate.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

This happens 
[image]

If i do labelfor like this

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CourseDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CourseDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

This happens: 
[image]

I want to fill the field and i can choose date from dropdown at the same time.

Comment: I believe the `CourseDate` is a `DateTime` property, and `model.CourseDate.Date` probably refers to `Date` property of `CourseDate` property. Note that `EditorFor` may render date input automatically for `DateTime` property, but not for `Date` property inside `DateTime` instance.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto you are probably right, i want both work in a way. I can not display current date and make the box open at the same time.

Comment: The second input you're seeing is for `<input type="date">` with spinner buttons, and the first input is a standard `<input type="text">`. If you want for both properties using same input type, use `TextBoxFor` helper decorated with `type="date"` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different representations here:

1) On the first `EditorFor`, it bounds for [`Date` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date) as part of `DateTime` instance in `CourseDate`, hence it rendered as plain textbox with `<input type="datetime" />`. Therefore,

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CourseDate.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

rendered as this:

```
<input id="CourseDate_Date" name="CourseDate.Date" type="datetime" value="...">
```

2) The second `EditorFor` bounds for `CourseDate` viewmodel property which defined as `DateTime`, hence an `<input type="date" />` is rendered. Therefore,

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CourseDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

rendered as this:

```
<input id="CourseDate" name="CourseDate" type="date" value="...">
```

Since your objective is allowing user to edit date inside the input directly together with date picker selection, the workaround is using `TextBoxFor` helper with `type="date"` attribute in `htmlAttributes`. Hence, your date inputs(s) should be formatted like example below:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CourseDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "form-control", type = "date" })
```

Note that `<input type="date" />` element requires value formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd` format to show its value according to [HTML date specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats), hence string formatting `{0:yyyy-MM-dd}` used to match that format.

[This fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/h99wud) contains example where user should able to input date components manually together with usage of date picker from `<input type="date" />` element.

Reference:

[HTML Date Input (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)

Comment: Thank you dude, i dont know the overload methods of the textboxfor so i can not try it in the app but after you gave the second parameter, now it works like charm.